# Docker: How to access the PM2 running inside docker in debug mode from localhost

Tags: node.js, docker, debugging, pm2

I am able to run the pm2 application inside docker in debug mode using the config like

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'api',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      script: './index.js',
      args: '--time',
      node_args: ["--inspect=9229"],
      log_date_format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss Z',
      instances: -1,
    },
  ],
}
```

I can see in the docker logs, these logs
`Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9230/beb99cb4-e9f6-4a7e-941f-d70b6391301f`

The pm2 is **running** at port `53007`
and **debugging** at port `9230`

I can able to access the running application from my localhost, but **what URL I should use in postman to hit the application running at debug mode ?**

Comment: If it's `listening on 127.0.0.1` then you can't access it from outside its own container.  Is there an option to change the bind or listen address to `0.0.0.0`?  At that point the debugger port would be like any other port and you can use a `docker run -p` option to publish it out to the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I did as you suggested, my question was how to access this URL `ws://127.0.0.1:9230/beb99cb4-e9f6-4a7e-941f-d70b6391301f`
This seem to be not a http, but ws.